# Parse JSON With HTML Tags and Quotes

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string coming into a function that looks like so:

```
properyCharacteristics  "{\"Key\":12345,\"values\":[\"<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.doamin.ca/residents/assessment/understand-assessment/assessment-glossary/index.htm#valuation_neighbourhood\">Valuation Neighbourhood Number</a>: <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{{GIS_TAX_WEB_VIEWER}}?resval=1622\" class=\"map-overlay-link\">1622</a>\"]}"
```

I am trying to parse this string using:

```
var data = JSON.parse(input);
```

but keep getting an "Invalid character" error.

Is it the \" that are invalid? I have tried using:

```
input.replace(/\"/g, "")
```

to remove those characters but I am still getting the "Invalid character" error.

Comment: have you tried `input.replace(/\"/g, "'") ` ?

Comment: There's not enough \s in the JSON to cover the inner (HTML) quotes, which is what's making the JSON invalid.

Comment: Can you replace the attribute quotes in html with single quotes before string is created? It's generally not a problem putting html in json when using proper JSON serializer which does the escaping. Problem lies at source of this string being created

Comment: @charlietfl "There's not enough \s in the JSON to cover the inner (HTML) quotes" Do I need to escape the \ with \\? I tried replace("\\", "\\\\"); but can't get it to work

Comment: @eag845 "have you tried input.replace(/\"/g, "'")" still gets invalid charater

Comment: Problem with simple `replace` is you only want to change what's inside the strings...not the string delimiter quotes

Comment: See what happens with single quoted html attributes here https://jsfiddle.net/b047oku3/. Fix the source of the string!

Comment: Here's an evil way of "fixing" this that shouldn't be used: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q30shc8u/6/

Comment: @ChrisG haha ya that's getting pretty hacky. Works though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotation marks *inside* the `HTML` string have to be escaped as `\\\"`. Simple `\"`-s become quotation marks for the JSON string itself, and then you have

```
{"Key":12345,"values":["<a target="_blank"
href="https://www.doamin.c....essment-glossary/index.htm#valuation_neighbourhood">
Valuation Neighbourhood Number</a>: <a target="_blank"
href="{{GIS_TAX_WEB_VIEWER}}?resval=1622"
class="map-overlay-link">1622</a>"]}
```

so a large number number of randomly placed quotation marks, making the entire thing invalid.

With double-escaping the internal part, it suddenly works:

```js
var text="{\"Key\":12345,\"values\":[\"<a target=\\\"_blank\\\" href=\\\"https://www.doamin.ca/residents/assessment/understand-assessment/assessment-glossary/index.htm#valuation_neighbourhood\\\">Valuation Neighbourhood Number</a>: <a target=\\\"_blank\\\" href=\\\"{{GIS_TAX_WEB_VIEWER}}?resval=1622\\\" class=\\\"map-overlay-link\\\">1622</a>\"]}";
console.log(JSON.parse(text));
```

Comment: That seems like a nightmare of a regular expression to try and write unfortunately lol

Comment: @J.Cart If it's possible, I would rather single-escape the HTML thing when wrapping it into the JSON, and then escaping the entire thing again when putting it into a string. Also, this construct in this form should not really occur in real-life code, I would rather assume that you wanted to test something, but in reality you will get the JSON via network requests. And then, the JSON itself needs no escaping, only the HTML, which you have done already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
properyCharacteristics = "{\"Key\":12345,\"values\":[\"<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.doamin.ca/residents/assessment/understand-assessment/assessment-glossary/index.htm#valuation_neighbourhood\">Valuation Neighbourhood Number</a>: <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{{GIS_TAX_WEB_VIEWER}}?resval=1622\" class=\"map-overlay-link\">1622</a>\"]}";
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(properyCharacteristics));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: That don't actually parse it unfortunately. I end up with same input string at the end instead of a JSON object